# Windows Spotlight no longer as wallpaper image

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

Before my laptop updated to the Win10 1903 version, it had this behavior: after entering my password, the wallpaper was the same as the picture of the lock screen, which was filled by Windows Spotlight.

After updating, the lock screen still has the Windows Spotlight functionality, but the wallpaper after entering the password has a Windows background. The options in the settings are: color, choose a picture, but not Windows Spotlight.

How can I restore the behavior that it had before? I have already disabled and enabled Windows Spotlight in the lock screen, but that didn't help.